# anonymous fields in JSON

Tags: json, go

I'm reverse engineering some JSON that seems to be using anonymous field names.  For example:

```
{
   "1": 123,
   "2": 234,
   "3": 345
}
```

BTW - it's not simply using "1" and "2" and "3" because they represent userids that are at a minimum int32's.

Is there some way such as using tags to properly Unmarshal the JSON?

I've tried:

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
)

type MyStruct struct {
        string `json:",string"`
}

func main() {
        jsonData := []byte("{\"1\":123,\"2\":234,\"3\":345}")

        var decoded MyStruct
        err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &decoded)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("decoded=%+v\n", decoded)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just decode the data into a map (`map[string]int`):

```
jsonData := []byte("{\"1\":123,\"2\":234,\"3\":345}")

var decoded map[string]int
err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &decoded)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

You'll then be able to iterate over and access the elements by the user ID key:

```
for userID, _ := range decoded {
    fmt.Printf("User ID: %s\n", userID)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/SJkpahGzJY